# NTLM based web service authenication in grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, ntlm, groovyws

How to connect to a web service that is on Microsoft stack and using NTLM based authentication, I have tried to use the groovy WS client, but I am not sure if I can achieve NTLM auth with this, can somebody tell me how can I do this in grails

Answer (score 0):

NTLM used to be supported by Spring security. 
Even though it is not supported any more there are still ways to use Spring to authenticate using NTLM.
And since Grails uses Spring underneath the hood you should be able to use this with Grails.

Have a look at this post: [Spring Security NTLM 3](http://aloiscochard.blogspot.se/2010/03/spring-security-ntlm-3.html)

Comment: Hello , I think this will be used when implemeting NTLM auth in our app, but in my case, I am trying to consume a web serice in my app which is hosted on some server that is using NTLM auth.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe this will help: [NTLM Authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#ntlm)